# ffmpeg image + audio to video, file size is very large?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a single image and a single audio file, and I'm trying to combine them into a video. The image is `186k` and the audio is `242k`, and the resulting `mp4` file is `928k`. Is this just one of those "Yeah, that's how that works", or can I do something to make the resulting video file smaller with my ffmpeg command? I'd like my output to be `h264` video, and the audio to have the same quality as the input. The image in the video should ideally be as high quality as the input.

My command is:

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a mp3 -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest result.mp4`

Are there any interesting flags I'm missing, or using any of those flags incorrectly? If the input file is `m4a`, do I still need to use mp3 for an `mp4` file?

Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Use `-crf [N]` to balance the size and image quality. The default value is 23. Use `-c:a copy` to keep audio quality.

Comment: Your JPG is one image. FFmpeg is generating a video stream at 25 fps of duration equal to the audio stream duration. This video stream will have keyframes at periodic intervals as well as all the intermediate predicted frames. These latter frames would be lightweight in your case, but in aggregate they will still take up some space.

Comment: Thanks! If you wanted to make these answers, I could choose one of them, and upvote both.